# Wildcard Search is not working in Amazon Cloudsearch as expected

Tags: java, php, solr, amazon-cloudsearch

While searching for "samsung galaxy j" , the AWS cloudsearch is giving me results like samsung galaxy j7,j5 and all (Giving only J series phones) . But while searching for samsung galaxy a, the result contains samsung galaxy j7,j5 along with samsung galaxy a5,a7 and all.

Why is this happening?

Queries:

For Query Samsung galaxy j as

```
[query] => samsung galaxy j*|"samsung galaxy j"
```

And for Samsung galaxy a as,

```
[query] => samsung galaxy a*|"samsung galaxy a"
```

And my indexed data as

```
Samsung Galaxy J7 4G
Samsung  Galaxy J5
Samsung Galaxy J7 4G
Samsung Galaxy J2
Samsung Galaxy A7
Samsung  Galaxy J5
```

Same thing happens for query **Samsung galaxy n**,It will give results like samsung galaxy note and all. But if I query for **Samsung galaxy no**
It will give  Samsung Galaxy J products

Am I missing something?. Please help

Comment: Could you please share the schema.XML used ...? Check if it has the stop word filter factory...

Comment: I am using Amazon Cloudsearch. Schema is $client->defineIndexField(array(
          'DomainName' => $this->_domain,
          'IndexField' => array(
               'IndexFieldName' => 'title',
               'IndexFieldType' => 'text',
               'TextOptions' => array(
                    'SearchEnabled' => true,
                    'FacetEnabled' => false,
                    'ReturnEnabled' => true,
                    'SortEnabled' => false,
                    'HighlightEnabled' => false,
                    )
               )
          ));

Comment: Abhijit's comment is correct, 'a' is a default stopword as per their spec. You should follow the instructions to disable it (if you wish so) here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/consoleguidev1/stopwords-help.html

Comment: @LijoAbraham : I would like to know the fieldType...what all it consist of...tokenizer and filter etc...

Comment: field type is text. Please check the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html